# Swift 4 - Getting half the width of a button

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, cornerradius

I'm trying to make a fully circular button. I have created it in code and setup the constraints like this:

```
    addButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.2).isActive = true
    addButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addButton.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    addButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
    addButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
```

I then try and set the corner radius of the button by using this:

```
    addButton.layer.cornerRadius = 
    addButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

But I don't know what to put in the corner radius. I have tried frame.width / 2 but the button remains square. I need to get the value of the width constraint but I can't convert it into a CGFloat.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: The thing is that using the corner radius to make the button circular is just such a silly and crude way to do this. If you want a button that looks circular, draw a circular background image and/or mask to a circle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews` put

```
addButton.layer.cornerRadius = self.view.frame.width * 0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the above answer posted by **@Sh_Khan** (url: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51808795/7425588) or go with the following:

```
addButton.layer.cornerRadius = addButton.widthAnchor.constant / 2.0
addButton.clipToBounds = true
```

Remember to make an UIObject complete circular, make it's height and width equal or aspect ratio to 1:1. Set clip to bounds to true and give corner radius as half of width or height.